# I lost all my stashed changes. How do I get them back?

Tags: laravel, git

I suddenly experienced a power outage since my laptop have no battery. How do I recover all those stashed work ?

[image]

Take a look at that it doesn't have any stash there.

Comment: If you in fact stashed before you lost power, the stash should still be there.

Comment: There's lots of stashes there But I can't seem to see them now

Comment: The image doesn't show anything helpful, I don't know if you intended it to show more than it does. In either case, please include commands, output, errors etc. as text. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: What is your OS ? Windows or linux ?

Answer (score 2):

Pre: start by making a backup of the `.git/` folder at the root of your repository.
Some operations may trigger git's garbage collection, which could delete files you wish to recover, making a copy of the `.git/` folder will allow you to replay your attempts at will.

---

1. the list of stashes is stored along with the reflogs, in a file `.git/logs/refs/stash`. Confirm that this file is empty :

   ```
   cat .git/logs/refs/stash
   ```
2. run `git fsck`, to see if it displays errors about invalid objects.
3. `git fsck` will list objects that are still stored somewhere in git, but are not referenced by any branch, tag or reflog.
   You are looking more specifically for commits, run :

   ```
   git fsck | grep commit > dangling-commits.txt
   ```
4. Check each of the dangling-commits, to see if you still see your stashed commits there.
   For example, you can run :

   ```
   cat dangling-commits.txt |\
   # each line should look like : dangling commit <sha>,
   # you want to take the 3rd column
       awk '{ print $3 }' |\
   # for each hash : run 'git log -1'
       xargs -L1 git log -1
   ```

You will see which of these commits look like stashed commmits : their message should look like :

```
WIP on [branchname]: [short hash] [commit message]
```

You will also see the date+time of their creation.

---

If you have found some of the commits you wish to keep, mark them with a tag or a branch, so that git will not delete them accidentally :

```
git tag [some name] [commit hash]

# e.g :
git tag backfromthedead/stash0 [commit hash]
```